blocked by CORS
Error en consola:
**Access to fetch at 'https://ts.bace.fr/dev/transcribe/uuid/06321e2c-04f9-408d-8324-e614252a6745?language=es&dictation_mode=true' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled**
    


**CURL:** curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://ts.bac/dev/transcribe/uuid/84acaa50-2f52-42c7-bbde-d2abd7d0c8a5?language=fr&dictation_mode=true' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Beare BPWbAn7tKJnyJLOkVglZAMkMa3FmjVQAcg' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'file=@Audio.wav;type=audio/wav'   


  

Muy buenas, he visto ya algunos post similares al mio pero su solución no me ha valido o quizas no la haya aplicado correctamente, decir que estoy usando un servidor local con XAMPP y que lo que pretendo es grabar un audio y enviarlo a una api.
Me da el error descrito arriba y no tengo forma de solucionarlo. Muchas gracias.
Indicar que usando Postman funciona correctamente.
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Grabador de Audio con Detección de Silencio</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/onnxruntime-web/dist/ort.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ricky0123/vad-web@0.0.7/dist/bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="audio" controls></audio>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <div id="params">
        <p>UUID: <span id="uuid"></span></p>
        <p>Token: <span id="token"></span></p>
    </div>
    <script>
        // Función para obtener parámetros de la URL
        function getQueryParams() {
            const params = {};
            const queryString = window.location.search.substring(1);
            const regex = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g;
            let match;
            while (match = regex.exec(queryString)) {
                params[decodeURIComponent(match[1])] = decodeURIComponent(match[2]);
            }
            return params;
        }

        const { uuid, token } = getQueryParams();
        document.getElementById("uuid").textContent = uuid || 'No proporcionado';
        document.getElementById("token").textContent = token || 'No proporcionado';

        let mediaRecorder;
        let audioChunks = [];
        let stream;
        let isRecording = false;

        // Función para enviar el archivo de audio a la API
        async function sendAudioToApi(audioBlob) {
            const myHeaders = new Headers();
            myHeaders.append("accept", "application/json");
            myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbuBXtQ");

            const formdata = new FormData();
            formdata.append("file", audioBlob, "audio.wav"); // Cambiar nombre del archivo
            formdata.append("uuid", uuid); // Agregar uuid si es necesario
            formdata.append("token", token); // Agregar token si es necesario

            const requestOptions = {
                method: "POST",
                headers: myHeaders,
                body: formdata,
                redirect: "follow"
            };

            fetch("http://ts.backev/cribe/uui-408d24-e2tation_mode=true", requestOptions)
                .then(response => response.text()) 
                .then(result => console.log("Respuesta de la API:", result))  // Salida más clara
                .catch(error => console.error("Error al enviar el audio:", error));
        }

        // Función para iniciar la grabación de audio
        async function startRecording() {
            if (isRecording) return; // No iniciar si ya está grabando
            try {
                stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
                mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

                mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
                    audioChunks.push(event.data);
                };

                mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
                    const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
                    document.getElementById("audio").src = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
                    audioChunks = [];
                    document.getElementById("status").innerText = "Grabación detenida.";
                    isRecording = false; // Cambia el estado a no grabando

                    // Enviar el archivo de audio a la API
                    sendAudioToApi(audioBlob);
                };

                mediaRecorder.start();
                document.getElementById("status").innerText = "Grabando...";
                isRecording = true; // Cambia el estado a grabando
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error accediendo al micrófono:", error);
                alert("No se pudo acceder al micrófono. Asegúrate de permitir el acceso.");
            }
        }

        // Iniciar la grabación y detección de voz al cargar la página
        window.onload = async () => {
            const myvad = await vad.MicVAD.new({
                startOnLoad: true,
                onSpeechStart: async () => {
                    console.log("User started talking");
                    await startRecording(); // Iniciar grabación inmediatamente al detectar habla
                },
                onSpeechEnd: () => {
                    console.log("User stopped talking");
                    if (isRecording) {
                        mediaRecorder.stop(); // Detener grabación si está grabando
                    }
                }
            });
            myvad.start(); // Inicia la detección de voz
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>

/************PHP/
<?php
// Obtener parámetros de la URL
$uuid = isset($_GET['uuid']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['uuid']) : 'No proporcionado';
$token = isset($_GET['token']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['token']) : 'No proporcionado';

 // Pintar los parámetros en la página
 echo "<p>$uuid</p>";
 echo "<p>$token</p>";

// Habilita la visualización de errores
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$url = 'https://ts.ribe/uuid/'.$uuid.'?language=es&dictation_mode=true'; // URL de la API
$filePath = 'C:/audio.wav'; // Ruta del archivo de audio

// Verifica si el archivo existe
if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
    die("El archivo $filePath no existe.");
}

// Crea el contenido del formulario multipart
$boundary = uniqid();
$headers = [
    "Authorization: Bearer $token",
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary"
];

$body = "--$boundary\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" . basename($filePath) . "\"\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Type: audio/wav\r\n\r\n";
$body .= file_get_contents($filePath) . "\r\n";
$body .= "--$boundary--\r\n";

// Configura el contexto para la solicitud POST
$options = [
    'http' => [
        'header'  => $headers,
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $body,
    ],
];

// Crea el contexto
$context = stream_context_create($options);

// Realiza la solicitud y obtiene la respuesta
$response = @file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

// Verifica si hubo un error
if ($response === FALSE) {
    echo "Error en la solicitud: " . error_get_last()['message'];
} else {
    // Imprime la respuesta sin decodificar
    echo "Respuesta cruda de la API: ";
    var_dump($response); // Muestra la respuesta cruda

    // Maneja la respuesta
    $result = json_decode($response, true); // Decodifica la respuesta JSON

    // Verifica si la decodificación fue exitosa
    if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        print_r($result); // Muestra la respuesta decodificada
    } else {
        echo "Error al decodificar la respuesta JSON: " . json_last_error_msg();
    }
}
?>


en tu request, estoy viendo que no le haz pasado el parametro de credentials: 'include', ahora no se si en este caso aplique porque solamente esto lo haces cuando trabajas con cookies o credenciales que necesitan ser enviadas entre el cliente y el servidor, especialmente en solicitudes cross-origin (diferente dominio)

Donde tendría que ponerlo?

en requestOptions puedes ponerlo alli el credentials: "include"

Nada, sigue dando el mismo error, y es un error que tengo yo, aqui Xampp tampoco pinta mucho por que cuando lanzo la pagina haciendo doble click sobre ella sin parar por el servidor localhost tambien me da el error

esta api, a la que estas haciendo el request, es una api de tercero o una ruta que tienes definido en tu backend?

Primordial entender algo.. CORS es un problema de los navegadores contra los backs, para evitar ataques desde ellos. POSTMAN no controla CORS, y por eso funciona. Es importante que tu back sepa que front los pueden llamar. no nos sirve ver tu front, tenemos que saber de tu back

Decir que si la petición la hago con php en el mismo servidor local de Xampp, funciona correctamente, la única diferencia es que el audio lo toma de una ruta de mi pc en este caso de c:\audio.wav. Entiendo que si fuera un tema que tuviera que modificar el server al que le quiero enviar el archivo, no me dejaría ni desde js ni desde php. Lo que pretendo es enviar un archivo para que me devuelva algo. Si lo necesitas por que te puede aclarar las cosas te puedo poner la llamada php. Gracias

La api a la que queres acceder es tuya?? no lo parece.. y si no es tuya, solo se puede acceder, segun lo que decis, desde un back.. deberias llegar desde tu php entonces, no desde tu js...

https://ts.bace.fr es tu dominio? Si vos controlas el servidor de esa página podes agregar el dominio de tu app a una especie de whitelist para que no se queje el CORS

no es exactamente ese, lo tengo cortado para no enseñarlo todo, tendré que hablar con la gente de ese dominio para ver que pasa...
